How to do a batch of changes in `about:config` in Firefox?
How to do a batch of changes in about:config in the Firefox?
Not one by one, but all together.
I want to set the batch of changes, but doing it one by one is exhausting.
How can I do it by a batch change?
media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled = false
browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground = true
browser.tabs.loadBookmarksInBackground = true
network.dns.blockDotOnion =false
browser.bookmarks.openInTabClosesMenu = false 
browser.tabs.insertAfterCurrent = true



Find your Firefox profile directory, which is usually in:
%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\
~/.mozilla/firefox/

You can also open it directly from about:support.

Close Firefox. Wait until firefox.exe exits.

Open the prefs.js file in a text editor and copy/paste the necessary user_pref() lines. You don't need to remove the old settings, just add new ones at the bottom



My prefs.js says "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE" at the top, and Mozilla's documentation says to create a user.js file instead. Is this answer correct?

@TomBrossman Reading the "Removing user.js entries" in your link above, I tend to believe that editing prefs.js directly is actually the most sane way. They don't merge the files (config hierarchy) on the fly, but instead they rewrite prefs.js based on user.js when the app is launched. user.js then prevents you from editing those flags in about:config, while direct prefs.js edits can be updated from there later... The only reason to use user.js is IMO that immutability (flags can only be changed for current session, but not permanently), if that isn't needed - make a backup and edit freely.

@SUTerliakov A small, but important, correction: by default, user.js doesn't prevent you from editing prefs in about:config.  Instead, it overwrites prefs when Firefox is launched.
